# How to update an MS Access table which contains auto-number columns from a pandas df?

Tags: pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I need to populate a table in MS Access using a pandas df. This table includes an auto-number column and another column with default value =now().

I tried to pass the following dataframe keeping the ID and RowInsertedTime columns as blank, however this hasn't worked out.

```
d = {'ID': ['',''], 'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'RowInsertedTime': ['','']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I executed my code using the pyodbc library as shown below:

```
connection_string = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Users\Public\MyTest.accdb;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

# insert the rows from the DataFrame into the Access table    
crsr.executemany(
    f"INSERT INTO [{table_name}] (ID, col1, col2, RowInsertedTime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
    df.itertuples(index=False))
```

Unfortunately this is returning the following error:

```
DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. (-3030) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Any idea how I can get the auto values for the blank fields showing inside my MS Access table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Autonumbering in Access - INSERT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771485/using-autonumbering-in-access-insert-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must leave out the columns you aren't updating.

```
crsr.executemany(
    f"INSERT INTO [{table_name}] (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)",
    df.itertuples(index=False))
```

Access will fill in the blanks.